# Wrapping text in HTML if condition is true

Tags: jquery, html

I need to wrap the text inside the `<a>` between `<div> .... </div>` tags in this HTML markup:

```
<li class="first current">
  <a href="http://dts.devserver/">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="last has_children sub-menu">
  <a href="http://dts.devserver/blog">Blog</a>
</li>
```

but only if the LI has has_children class so the result should be:

```
<li class="first current">
  <a href="http://dts.devserver/">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="last has_children sub-menu">
  <a href="http://dts.devserver/blog"><div>Blog</div></a>
</li>
```

Which jQuery code or method or property I should use? Can any help here?

Comment: @JamesMontagne I mean wrap "Blog" in this case inside `<div>...</div>` tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.wrappInner` combined with simple selector will do it.

```
$('li.has_children a').wrapInner("<div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the code below helps. http://jsfiddle.net/HKm5S/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('li').each(function () {

    if ($(this).hasClass('has_children')) {
        var text = $(this).find('a').html();
        $(this).find('a').html("<div>" + text + "</div>");
    }
});
});
```